# Highchart change bar color based on top three highest and lowest value on data

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using Highcharts in my project and I get stuck when I want to apply a requirement that requires me to change bar color dynamically to green, yellow and red. The green one is used to color the value data that belong to top three highest numbers. The red one is used to color the value data that belong to bottom three numbers on data. Another value gets yellow.

This is my Highcharts code in JS:

```
$(function(){
    $('#directorate-culture-index-comparison-chart').highcharts({
        chart:{
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title : {
            text : ''
        },
        legend :{
            enabled : false
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories : [dir1, dir2, dir3,dir4 , dir5,dir6,dir7]

        },
        plotOptions :{
            series : {
                colorByPoint : true,
                dataLabels : {
                    enabled : true,
                    align : 'right',
                    color : "#fff"
                }
            }
        },
        yAxis : {
            title : {
                text: "Score"
            },
            plotLines: [{
                color: 'red',
                value:  val_culture_index, // Insert your average here
                label : {
                    text: val_culture_index,
                    style: {
                        color: 'blue',
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        fontSize : 18
                    }
                },
                width: '1',
                zIndex: 100 // To not get stuck below the regular plot lines
            }],
            min : 0,
            max : 5
        },
        credits:{
            enabled : false
        },
        series : [{
            data : [val_culture_index_JKTDC, val_culture_index_JKTDE, val_culture_index_JKTDF, val_culture_index_JKTDI, val_culture_index_JKTDN,val_culture_index_JKTDO,val_culture_index_JKTDZ]
        }],
    });
});
```

Comment: please fiddle your code :)

Comment: How your data looks like ?

Comment: I want to do this too !